# Form security to prevent value change via browser dev tool

Tags: php

So I have a `<select>` where the options are **not** getting populated from the database.

Now based on the access level of an user the options are limited.

How can I stop a scenario where the user changes the option value to something that exists but not allowed for his access level.

**Example - Grade Options**:

```
Teacher     Principal
 - A         - O
 - B         - E
 - C         - A
             - B
             - C
```

How to stop teacher from entering O or E in the `<select>` from the browser dev tool. Provided the grades are not coming from the database rather being hard coded in the form with if conditions based on if its teacher or prinicipal.

Comment: If you're relying on client-side code, you basically can't stop them submitting whatever they like (see Firefox's Tamper plugin for instance https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/); anything can be tweaked. You'll need to authenticate the user on the server with the form submission. However, if you just want to remove the options from the list for keeping the GUI clean, use PHP to output only the options the user is allowed to select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the option after submit if the user has a permission for this in every case. You can use **javascript to give the user a hint** before submitting the form **but you have also to check the values that are received in your receiving php script** before storing it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent user from posting whatever they want.

There is only thing you can do about it. Secure it in your PHP code.